# $2n=n^2$ what are the solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have just thought of this and I know someone must have before but is the only solution (with real numbers) to $2n=n^2$

$n=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2n=n^2\iff n^2-2n=0\iff n(2-n)=0\iff \begin{cases}n=0\\ n=2\end{cases}$$

Comment: So this is only true for 0 and 2 ? What if we ignore my request for real numbers is there any cases where imaginary numbers follow this rule?

Comment: Yes, it's true only for n=2 and n=0.

Comment: Thank you I will accept as soon as the timer is up

Comment: Consider changing the signs inside the parenthesis (not a big deal)..

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo nope, $n(2-n)$ is a product of $n$ and $2-n$, therefore $n(2-n)=0$ holds whenever any or both of the products are evaluated to zero. Therefore you have two equations, and if $n$ is a solution to any of them, it is also a solution to the original equation.

Comment: @idm I suppose the curly brace you used stands for logical conjunction, while a square bracket or ``\lor`` (disjunction) should be used.

Answer (score 2):

$$n^2 = 2n \iff n^2 - 2n = 0 \iff n(n-2) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$2n=n^2$ is a quadratic equation. So it has two solutions.

In particular, $2n=n^2$ if and only if $$n^2-2n=0 \tag{1}$$
 Comparing (1) with $an^2+bn+c=0$, we see that $a=1, b=-2$, $c=0$. Now, $b^2-4ac=4>0$. Hence, the two solutions of $2n=n^2$ are both real numbers.

**The two (real) solutions of $2n=n^2$ are $n=0$ or $2$.**

Comment: You can get a label like "(1)" by using `\tag{1}` within the equation.

Comment: @ Theophile, tnx...will do the editing now.

Answer (score 0):

A distinct approach may utilize calculus. The two trivial cases are $n=0$ and $n=2$. To prove that these are the only solutions to $2n=n^2$, simply note that $\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = 2x$ > $\frac{d}{dx} 2x = 2$ for $x≥2$. In other words, at $x=2$ the functions are equal, and for greater $x$ the $x^2$ will always be increasing at a faster rate thus they can never be equal again ($2x$ cannot "catch up" so to speak).

Comment: Thank you for this it helped explain the answer more clearly